# Efficiently calculating rolling row summation in R

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I need to compute a rolling row sum of a column in a data frame which has a condition involved. The data that I have has multiple observations for a "sku". What I want is to calculate the sum of 5 consecutive rows for every value of "sku". In case I reach a stage where I do not have 5 consecutive observations for "sku" we would sum up the remaining row observations for that respective value.

For an illustrative example consider the following data frame:

```
data <- structure(list(sku = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), tf = c(50.79, 46.39, 47.85, 45.79, 44.46, 49.99, 
                                                   46.12, 44.4, 41.21, 53.7, 53.9, 44.91, 59.64, 41.96, 52.26, 43.48, 
                                                   46.93, 51.2, 54.31, 42.5, 47.2, 57.54, 63.23, 48.98, 52.38, 59.9, 
                                                   53.01, 50.35, 41.86, 46.42)), .Names = c("sku", "tf"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                  -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

In this dataframe, we want to sum up the variable "tf" for 5 rolling values of each "sku" value.

We have been able to accomplish that using the following code:

```
data[,c("day_5")]<-unlist(mapply(function(y){
end1<-(which(data$sku==unique(data$sku)[y]))[length(which(data$sku==unique(data$sku)[y]))]  
start<-(which(data$sku==unique(data$sku)[y]))[1]
d<-data$tf[start:end1]
r<-mapply(function(x){if (x+4 <= length(d)) {sum(d[x:(x+4)])} else {sum(d[x:length(d)])}},1:length(d))
},1:length(unique(data$sku))))
```

Column "day_5" gives us exactly what we want but this method turns out to be very inefficient as we have to run this operation on millions of rows of data with thousands of values of "sku".

Can someone help us optimize this code in a fashion that we can scale it up to a large data?

Comment: the `zoo` package has many rolling functions including `rollsum`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With huge datasets you should use package data.table. Package zoo provides functions for rolling means, sums and applies.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data)

library(zoo)
fun <- function(x, i) {
  x <- c(x, rep(0, i-1))
  rollsumr(x, k=i)
}

DT[, day_5a:=fun(tf,5), by=sku]
print(DT)

#     sku    tf  day_5 day_5a
# 1:    1 50.79 235.28 235.28
# 2:    1 46.39 234.48 234.48
# 3:    1 47.85 234.21 234.21
# 4:    1 45.79 230.76 230.76
# 5:    1 44.46 226.18 226.18
# 6:    1 49.99 181.72 181.72
# 7:    1 46.12 131.73 131.73
# 8:    1 44.40  85.61  85.61
# 9:    1 41.21  41.21  41.21
# 10:   2 53.70 254.11 254.11
# 11:   2 53.90 252.67 252.67
#<snip>
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing the function from Ronald, a simpler way might be to use:

```
fun <- function(x, i) {
  x <- c(x, rep(0, i-1))
  rollsumr(x, k=i)
}
data$day_5_a <- ave(data$tf, data$sku, FUN= function(x) fun(x, 5))
```

Comment: I don't think `ave` is simpler. However, it will be much slower with millions of observations and thousands of groups.

Answer (score 1):

Using only `base` (*obviously* less efficient and less elegant than `data.table`):

```
data_ls <- split(data, data$sku)

res <- lapply(data_ls, 
           function(z) sapply(1:length(z$tf), 
               function(vec, x) { sum(vec[x:(x+4)], na.rm = T) }, 
                 vec = z$tf))

data$day_5 <- unlist(res)

#> data
#   sku    tf  day_5
#1    1 50.79 235.28
#2    1 46.39 234.48
#3    1 47.85 234.21
#4    1 45.79 230.76
#5    1 44.46 226.18
#6    1 49.99 181.72
#7    1 46.12 131.73
#8    1 44.40  85.61
#9    1 41.21  41.21
#10   2 53.70 254.11
#11   2 53.90 252.67
#12   2 44.91 242.25
```

Comment: Please don't use two nested loops. If you want to stay in base, here is a possibility that then can be combined with functions like `ave` or `tapply`: `fun <- function(x, i) rev(na.omit(filter(c(rep(0,i-1),rev(x)),rep(1,i),sides=1)))`

Comment: @Roland: Well, that's good! Thanks! I guess you should edit your answer adding a `base` alternative and I'll delete this approach instead of editing it using your function.

Comment: I don't think you should use base for this. The question title asks for efficiency and I don't think you can beat data.table.

Comment: @Roland: I dug a bit in `filter` and ended up in [`filter.c`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/src/filter.c). I, for sure, have no clue what's going on but the `for`s caught my eye. Is `filter` `loop`-like, too? If so, is it more efficient than `lapply`s? Excuse my ignorance, though, if I've missed something obvious; I'm just curious.

Comment: You have to distinguish between R loops and C loops. The latter are the basis of all "vectorized" R functions and since they are compiled code they are faster by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Roland: Sorry to bother again. Isn't `lapply` in the "C loop" category too?

Comment: Strictly speaking yes, but it's a special case, since you pass it an R function, which makes it similar to a `for` loop (which is also implemented in C). Loops in R are pretty fast. What happens inside (e.g., the repeated evaluation of R functions) is slow. Vectorized functions don't evaluate R functions.

Comment: @Roland: Many thanks for your time! I appreciate it. :) We can delete the unnecessary comments if you'd like. Thanks, again!